# Java use streams to modify nested list and return parent list

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have following dto

```
public class StepsDto {
    
    private String step_name;
    private String status;
    private List<StepsDto> sub_steps;
    private String previousStep;
    private String nextStep;
}
```

Using streams I need to change the status of Substeps if name of a particular step and its substep and its sub sub step matches.
And then I need to return the complete Parent list of Steps.

I have tried using flatmap but it returns sublist and not the main list.

So for example I have parent step P1,child step C1 and in the child I have another child CC1. I want to change the status of CC1 and return the Parent list.

Comment: It's not clear what you want, and what kind of matching you are looking for.
You are talking 3 levels of steps, and want to update the status for 2nd level? And that is supposed to happen when the name of a step matches the name of parent step and has any child step with similar name?

Comment: The name of step and sub steps will always be different. Yes I have 3 levels of step and first attribute is step name.
I want to change the status at 3rd level only.
So for example I have parent step P1,child step C1 and in the child I have anther child CC1.
I want to change the status of CC1 and return the Parent list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying what kind of stream usage you are looking for. You don't need `flatMap` because you are not going to update the structure of the list but only modify the values in it.

You can forcibly use the `stream()` to iterate over your lists and update the values in place.

```
    List<StepsDto> l1steps = new ArrayList<>();

    l1steps.stream().forEach(l1step -> {
        l1step.sub_steps.stream().forEach(l2step -> {
            l2step.sub_steps.stream().forEach(l3step -> {
                if(l3step.step.equals(l2step.step) && l3step.step.equals(l1step.step)){
                    l3step.status = "newStatus";
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify the values in place, instead of `foreach` you could use `map` while creating new instances of steps each time.

```
    List<StepsDto> result = l1steps.stream().map(l1step -> {
        List<StepsDto> l1SubSteps = l1step.sub_steps.stream().map(l2step -> {
            List<StepsDto> l2SubSteps = l2step.sub_steps.stream().map(l3Step -> {
                return new StepsDto(l3Step.step, l3Step.status.equals(l2step.status) && l3Step.status.equals(l1step.status) ? "newStatus" : l3Step.status, l3Step.sub_steps, l3Step.previousStep, l3Step.nextStep);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new StepsDto(l2step.step, l2step.status, l2SubSteps, l2step.previousStep, l2step.nextStep);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new StepsDto(l1step.step, l1step.status, l1SubSteps, l1step.previousStep, l1step.nextStep);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for this I was avoiding foreach due to complexity can you also provide the solution using map.
The above solution is exactly what I want.

Comment: `stream().forEach(...)` provides little benefit over just `List#forEach`. With that in mind, this isn't really a "stream" solution as much as a triple loop, which is what (imo) the question really called for to begin with.

Comment: @GauravMatta added an example with `map` for you

Answer (score 0):

you could do this as follows

```
substeps.stream().filter(x -> x.status == originalStatus)
.map(x -> x.substeps).flatMap(Collection::stream).filter(x -> x.status == originalStatus)
.findFirst()
```

What happens above is that you take the substeps of you parent step,

you filter out the steps with different status

then you map each substep to its substeps : this gives you a stream of lists of steps, the flatmap will "remove the list layer" and will return a stream of all the grandchildren steps

then you filter out the grand children with a different status.

theoritically, the remaining step will have the same status as their parent and grandparent.

you can test further into the hierarchy by adding extra map.flatmap.filter steps

Comment: you won't compare the status with ==, since it is a string.

Comment: comparing strings by reference (using == operator) will work as expected 99.9% of the time since the JVM interns strings automatically, but you are right, it is good practice to use equals() instead ;)